# ERD Review for Chipotle Order System

Tags: mysql, database-design, erd

Attached is the ERD for my attempt at creating an ERD of Chipotles order system. I've been trying to learn how to make good ERD for database design and wanted to get some feedback.

I'm confused on some structural parts like the **tb_meal** to **tb_meal_item**, **tb_protein**, etc. Wondering if those relationships shown in the attached ERD breaks any normalization up to 3rd form or not. The options for creating a meal are finite, so there's going to be duplicate meals in tb_meal where the only varying factor is the incremental meal id. I suppose maybe the answer is to store all combinations of tb_meal, but then the lookup and association to an order seems like a waste of time unless I make all the combinations composite keys, but that seems like an adhoc solution? The cardinality stuff has me wondering if some **many-to-one** or **many-to-many** kind of relationships opt towards making a database un-normalalized. Here's the link to Chipotles website to kind of see where I'm coming from in terms of trying to model the ERD: https://www.chipotle.com/
[image: Chiptole ERD Design]

Comment: What's with this `tb_` crap? ERD stands for "entity-relationship diagram", so do you have a "tb_user" entity, or a "user" entity? Also, `tb_meal` suggests that you only have one topping per meal; why is then the attribute name in plural? If instead you can have more than one topping, then your model is incorrect.

Comment: Yikes. I'm just trying to learn and just asking for help, no need to be aggressive. I appreciate the feedback on removing "tb_" from the names. I put them there to show it will be a table in the db with the following attributes. Removing the 's' from the tables makes sense. Again, a rough draft, but I wanted to see if the overall structure made sense or where improvement to the relation could be made.

Can you elaborate on the cardinality between meal and topping?

Comment: You are running ahead of yourself, thinking about tables. An ERD is a tool for logical modelling, which deals with abstract entities. You turn to the physical modelling, where tables and other things appear, once your logical model is complete and consistent. Not sure what you want to know about toppings; I don't know how many toppings that Chipotle guy allows you to choose, but you probably do. So, how many? That would be your cardinality.

Comment: Drop the `id` columns, they are a physical consideration (row identifiers) and not actual data.  If you do use them (say, for `User`), context is important.  Always the entity name + id.  You shouldn't have multiple tables for each ingredient, either have a table for ingredients and something that ties which options are available for each menu item.  Subtypes may be involved.

Comment: @mustaccio, understood on the part for what ERD is aimed for. A meal can have multiple different toppings, like guacamole, fresh tomato salsa, fajita veggies, etc, but you can't have like 2 guacamoles for one meal.

Comment: "I figure if I can separate things to their base values (assuming there's multiple options) then I should." No.  You need to understand the hierarchy of the entities you're modeling and (possibly) subtypes.  What if there's a new ingredient?  What if not every menu item can use that ingredient?  Not everything is a burrito.

Comment: @bbaird The multiple tables like protein, rice, and bean was because each section has multiple options and for some of the sections the price varies such as protein (chicken $8.85 vs $steak 10.60) Protein: Chicken, Steak, Carnitas, etc., rice: white, brown, jasmine, none, bean: black, pinto red none. There are like 10 sides too (guacamole, sour cream, cheese, etc. I figure if I can separate things to their base values (assuming there's multiple options) then I should. I suppose I could just remove the entities and turn them instead into attributes and have the front end keep track of the price

Comment: Understood, I'll try to think of a better structure.

Comment: I assume cheese is a `topping`?...surely you can ask for double / extra cheese at Chipotle. Same is true for most toppings or really any of the ingredients you can choose from there. Agreed with bbaird that a single generic table for all ingredients, is probably a more logical design. You would just need the appropriate columns to qualify any differences (like if only certain ingredients can be ordered with extra, then a boolean field `AllowsExtra` etc). I would not recommend tracking data points in the application side, no need to scrap the entities entirely.

Comment: Let's see the main `SELECTs` that you will be using.  I ask for those because you will eventually need the `SELECTs` _and_ the exercise will give you insight into what the schema is like.

Comment: What if a user wants 2 sides?  (I think you need to start over.)